# Get data from DataObject csv file javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

I read a csv file using the code

```
var x="dema.csv";
loadCSV(x);

function loadCSV(file) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        var request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }
    // load
    request.open('GET', file, false);
    request.send();
    parseCSV(request.responseText);
}
```

I put the data into a dataObject using this code

```
function parseCSV(data, dataArray) {
    //replace UNIX new lines
    data = data.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
    //replace MAC new lines
    data = data.replace(/\r/g, "\n");
    //split into rows
    var rows = data.split("\n");

    // loop through all rows
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        // this line helps to skip empty rows
        if (rows[i]) {
            // our columns are separated by comma
            var column = rows[i].split(",");


            var date=column[0];
            var value = column[4];
            var dataObject = {
                date: date,
                T4: value
            };
        /
            dataArray.push(dataObject);
        }
    }

}
```

I get only the date column and T4 column. my problem is that i wanna some way to do some processing ( for loops to verify some conditions (ex: T4 shouldn't surpass 700 over 30 s))
Can i do it only using a dataObject or use a 2D array? how can i get the cells content using the right tool?

Comment: @julekgwa can you help me with that

Comment: what is the structure of your csv?

Comment: paste the data in  this variable `data`

Comment: @julekgwa i dont understand why should i paste daa in data variable

Comment: I want to know what is in `data` variable.

Comment: @julekgwa i think is the file data gotten from loadcsv function

Comment: It will be better to know the structure of the csv file, now I'm working blindly without knowing the what the csv file contains.

Comment: @julekgwa here is an image of the file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143223/discussion-between-julekgwa-and-s-elbahloul).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x = "dema.csv";
var dataArray = [];

loadCSV(x);

function loadCSV(x) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            parseCSV(this.responseText, dataArray);

            // you can loop over the array like this
            //dataArray.forEach((line) => {
            // here line contains data, time, tops, cycle, T4, test
            // you can access them like line.time, line.T4, line.tops etc
            // console.log(line.time);
            // console.log(line.tops);
            // etc
            //});
            window.alert(dataArray[0].T4);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", x, true);
    xhttp.send();
}

function parseCSV(data, arr) {
    //replace UNIX new lines
    data = data.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
    //replace MAC new lines
    data = data.replace(/\r/g, "\n");
    //split into rows
    var rows = data.split("\n");

    // loop through all rows
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        // this line helps to skip empty rows
        if (rows[i] && i > 0) {
            // our columns are separated by comma
            var column = rows[i].split(",");
            var dataObject = mapValuesToObj(column);
            arr.push(dataObject);
        }
    }
}

function mapValuesToObj(csvLine) {
    var absTime = csvLine[0];
    var time = csvLine[1];
    var tops = csvLine[2];
    var cycle = csvLine[3];
    var t4 = csvLine[4];
    var test = csvLine[5];
    return {
        date: absTime,
        time: time,
        tops: tops,
        cycle: cycle,
        T4: t4,
        test: test
    };
}
```

Comment: suppose it works how can i get the content of a cell (ex:the forth element of T4 column)

Comment: for example `T4 = 150`, to get the first element you can use `T4[0]`

Comment: means when the server  request is ok or successful

Comment: T4[0] doesn't return anything? dataArray when we use it?

Comment: `console.log(dataArray[0].T4[0])`

Comment: i use this code to get T4[0]  `<body>
        <h1>Affichage</h1>
       <script type="text/javascript">
      
       window.alert(dataArray.T4[0]); 
       </script>
      
    </body>
 but i dont get anything`

Comment: i wil share it here

Comment: window.alert(dataArray[0].T4[0]);  it gives me T if i put  window.alert(dataArray[0].T4[1]); it gives

Comment: yes, it works. thank you very much for your help, thank you again

Comment: how to get rows.length

Comment: use `dataArray.length` not `rows.length`